# Analyze Screenshots with c++ and GDI to get average color of screen

Tags: c++, bitmap, screenshot, gdi, pixel

I am working on a project that I am trying to design for a class. I want to try and mimic the behavior of Phillips' Abilight or the common homebrew 'BobLight'. It gets the average color of the screen,via screenshot, in my case by averaging the RGB pixel data, pixel by pixel. I have decided to try and do this by using the windows GDI api and so far I am getting some pretty good results, I learned not to use GetPixel() to read pixel data since its so incredibly slow, and my speed is perfectly acceptable so far.

My problem is that when I try to implement it in a loop that can run as long as desired, it eventually hangs giving me an error saying: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0027F9C4.

at this line of code:

```
BYTE *lpbitmap = new BYTE[dwBmpSize];
```

I attached my entire code below
Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this error? Am I shouldn't be running out of any kind of memory, and I'm really at a loss..
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT    0x0501        //xp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_FRAMES 180

using namespace std;


int main()
{ 
    int time_start, time_finish;
    float time_total;
    time_start = clock();

for(int z = 0; z < NUM_FRAMES; z++)
{

HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);     
// and a device context to put it in
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

int x = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
int y = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, x, y);

// get a new bitmap
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);


RECT desktop;
// Get a handle to the desktop window
const HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
// Get the size of screen to the variable desktop
GetWindowRect(hDesktop, &desktop);
// The top left corner will have coordinates (0,0)
// and the bottom right corner will have coordinates
// (horizontal, vertical)
int horizontal = desktop.right;
int vertical = desktop.bottom;


BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, horizontal, vertical, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);

BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
bi.biWidth = horizontal;    
bi.biHeight = vertical;  
bi.biPlanes = 1;    
bi.biBitCount = 32;    
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
bi.biClrImportant = 0;

DWORD dwBmpSize = ((horizontal * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * vertical;

// Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper     functions that 
// call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc     and LocalAlloc 
// have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND,dwBmpSize); 
BYTE *lpbitmap = new BYTE[dwBmpSize]; 



//BITMAP bm;
GetDIBits(hMemoryDC,hBitmap,0,(UINT)vertical,lpbitmap, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
GetObject (hBitmap, sizeof(lpbitmap), &lpbitmap);


unsigned long red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < horizontal; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < vertical; j++)
    {
    blue += lpbitmap[0];
    green += lpbitmap[1];
    red += lpbitmap[2];

    lpbitmap += 4;
    }
}

red = red/(horizontal*vertical);
green = green/(horizontal*vertical);
blue = blue/(horizontal*vertical);

//cout << "Red: " << red << "    Green: " << green << "    Blue: " << blue << endl;
}
time_finish = clock();
time_total = time_finish - time_start;

cout << endl << NUM_FRAMES/((time_total)/10000) << endl;
    //release
    //DeleteDC(hdc);
    //DeleteObject(hbmp);
    //ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);

        std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your release code appears to be commented out, meaning you're at least leaking `hBitmap` every frame, which will add up quickly (around 470MB/s to be specific).  Actually, it looks like you're leaking `lpbitmap` as well, so your 180 frames will burn about 2.8 GB on a 1080p display.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, should I be deleting the device contexts or really just lpbitmap, since thats the only thing I'm allocating myself?

Comment: You should ideally allocate memory up front outside of the loop, and only recreate it if the display mode changes.  You'll need to release both `lpbitmap` and `hBitmap` (possibly others) since you create them both. Just because an object isn't created with `new` doesn't mean you don't need to destroy it.

Comment: So if I allocate space for lpbitmap outside the for loop then it can just refill the pointer using DIBits, and not need to allocate more memory on each iteration right? 

When I want to delete lpbitmap I can just use:
    delete lpbitmap;
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

Comment: Yes, but be sure to use the arrayed version of delete - `delete [] lpbitmap;`.

Comment: When I allocate the memory outside of the loop I get access errors saying that I there is nothing inside lpbitmap, and when I allocate it and delete it inside the loop each for each frame, i can get to about 1003 pixels before getting a similar error..